# Is this a Discrete uniform probability distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

This might be a simple question but I'm having trouble figuring out what kind of probability distribution this question is.

---

Sam has a 2/3 chance of scoring a point each time she throws from the free-throw line in basketball. (You should assume that the probability of success for each throw is independent of the result of other attempts.)

What is the expectation of the number of points that Sam will score from 3 throws?

What is the variance of the number of points that Sam will score from 3 throws?

---

I know I could solve the questions using the formula, but first I need to know what kind of probability distribution this is.

I think it is a discrete uniform distribution but I'm not too sure about this.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it's a uniform distribution? The number of points Sam will score in $3$ throws could be either $0,1,2$ or $3$; do you think all of these outcomes have the same chance of occurring?

Comment: @Bergson, is it not? The question said that sam has a 2/3 chance of scoring a point each time she throws and that the probability of success is independent.

Comment: You might want to read about the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).